# Unable to publish on topic because of security policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

I have an IoT thing that was working with the SDK sample from Amazon with no issues.

However, it is time to adjust the rules and I ended with this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account_id>:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account_id>:topic/telemetry/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

With the rules above, my device can connect, but cannot publish or subscribe to the topic.

I want to my thing be capable to publish and subscribe in `telemetry/<THINGNAME>/<anything>`.

How to fix my rules to allow that topic?

Comment: you need to add iot:connect, iot:subscribe and iot:receive. Each one of them have a different Resource pattern. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html